# apache-artemis 2.13.0 - why broker issues AM1212037 connection failure and AMQ214013 Failed to decode packet message in ogs

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have setup the Aretmis in HA configuration (one node as master and another as backup in different VMs)
From logs, i see the backup is announced, the configuration is similar to the [config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62218408/apache-activemq-artemis-client-reconnecting-to-next-available-broker-in-clustere)

When clients connecting to the Broker from multiple VMs, i notice the broker (master) logs is displaying the below message more often.

I see some anonymous nodes i sending some message which is not able to decode. but not sure how to debug or resolve it exactly.

Key config is:
i am using `<acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61617?amqpIdleTimeout=0;tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>`.

Notice the ip address 0.0.0.0 ip address, rather than localhost or ip-address of that VM/node.

When using the acceptor with **localhost** the clients are not able to discover the broker, so someone recommended to use 0.0.0.0. And when using localhost i don't see the below message.

Below message keeps on filling up the artemis.log. Any inputs?

```
WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to /x.x.x.x:30001 has been detected: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AMQ219032: Invalid type: 1 [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]

 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ214013: Failed to decode packet: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AMQ219032: Invalid type: 1

  at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.PacketDecoder.decode(PacketDecoder.java:481) [artemis-core-client-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ClientPacketDecoder.decode(ClientPacketDecoder.java:67) [artemis-core-client-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ServerPacketDecoder.slowPathDecode(ServerPacketDecoder.java:273) [artemis-server-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ServerPacketDecoder.decode(ServerPacketDecoder.java:149) [artemis-server-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:377) [artemis-core-client-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(RemotingServiceImpl.java:667) [artemis-server-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:73) [artemis-core-client-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:321) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:295) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.handlerRemoved(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:253) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:505) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:437) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ProtocolHandler$ProtocolDecoder.channelRead(ProtocolHandler.java:142) [artemis-server-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:792) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:475) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
```

Most of our clients/consumers where Camel (2.20.0) version context, and as mentioned in (link)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41157708/amq214013-failed-to-decode-packet-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-amq11903] there are no servers connected.

Similar to this (ticket)[http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Error-while-master-boots-up-td4707407.html] in my case the connector configuration

Say master host name  is `master-vm` and ip is x.x.x.x
and backup is `backup-vm` and ip is y.y.y.y

Master broker.xml:

```
    <connector name="netty-connector"> tcp://x.x.x.x:61616</connector>
    <connector name="broker1"> tcp://backup-vm:61616</connector>
```

Backup broker.xml:

```
    <connector name="netty-connector"> tcp://y.y.y.y:61616</connector>
    <connector name="broker2"> tcp://master-vm:61616</connector>
```

And Master and backup, configured to statically discover each other.

---

Sample client: (camel context used)

```xml
  <bean id="jmsConnxionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory">
          <constructor-arg index="0" value="tcp://master-vm:61616?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=500000"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="jmsPooledConnxionFactory" class="org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="5" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnxionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsPooledConnxionFactory" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
  </bean>
```

Comment: What connectionFactory are you using?

Comment: I have included the sample client connection (updated question), using camel-spring bean way, 

<bean id="jmsConnxionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory">
          <constructor-arg index="0" value="tcp://master-vm:61616?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=500000"/>
  </bean>

Answer (score 2):

In a way it was due to configuration reason.

I modified the default generated `<accpetor>` element in the broker.xml, i kept only the ampq acceptor tag alone. Not sure whether this was the reason for this issue.

with the default config below, i was able to benefit

- logs not growing now
- there was NO client side changes required, the broker processing message with the Apache ActiveMq init context itself (not artemis specific context).

```
<acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

<!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
<acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
```