# Apache Artemis - logs AMQ212037 connection failure and connection reset by peer [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-artemis

Artemis is configured in HA, with one master and a backup slave in different VM's.

The `broker.xml` configuration uses static discovery options and the acceptors, 61616 supporing all the protocols, and AMQP.

The configuration is similar to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63095573/apache-artemis-2-13-0-why-broker-issues-am1212037-connection-failure-and-amq21)

artemis.log (below issue is continuously logged)

```
WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to <ip-address> has been detected: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
```

From the logs, the ip-address info it seems to be one of the clients/consumer is pushing this info.

In another post [link](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Artemis-2-6-3-Multicast-consumer-via-HTTP-transport-AMQ212037-Connection-failure-has-been-detected-td4744416.html) it was recommended to use `confirmationWindowSize`. But not sure whether this is applicable for my case.

The client configuration is using Camel and the ActiveMQ OpenWire client version 5.13.2 to connect:

```xml
    <bean id="conxnFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
      <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://domain-name:port" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pooledconxnFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
      <property name="maxConnections" value="5" />
      <property name="connectionFactory" ref="conxnFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="config" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
      <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledconxnFactory" />
      <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsqueue" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
      <property name="configuration" ref="config" />
    </bean>
    
    <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
      <endpoint id="inputQueue" uri="jmsqueue:queue:dataqueue1" />
      
      <route>
        <from uri="ref:inputQueue" />
        <!-- process -->
        <to uri="ref:outputQueue"/> <!-- endpoint defined already not included in here-->
        ...
        ...
```

Any inputs/ideas, why this occurs.

Comment: If the broker is reporting this it seems like there may be an issue with the client. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean) for more details on what the error actually means. Is there a specific reason you're using the OpenWire client? Also, what version of the client are you using?

Comment: The recommendation you cited about using `confirmationWindowSize` will almost certainly *not* help in this case. The recommendation was based on the use of the HTTP transport with the Artemis core JMS client. You are not using either of these.

Comment: In our case we don't want the change the client side configuration due to legacy code complication. So we retained the apache camel 2.20.0 version and client info is similar as mentioned. 
I think that uses the OpenWire protocol not AMQP.  I need to check if it can be modified to use AMPQ without much changes.

Comment: openwire client is activemq-client 5.13.2 version.

Comment: Is this something you can reproduce? If so, could you work up a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Will check the link you shared, and provide steps or info to reproduce this.