# Send AMQ Message using ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: java, wildfly, jboss-arquillian, activemq-artemis

I want to send a message to an ActiveMQ Artemis instance on a WildFly server. I am using [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuring_messaging/acceptors_and_connectors) tutorial in trying to configure the `standalone-full.xml`. I am using the [jboss/wildfly](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly/) docker image and am exposing the below netty port: `5445`.

Standalone configuration:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:10.0">
    <server name="default">
        <security enabled="true"/>
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="SuperUser" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10" redistribution-delay="1000"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
        <remote-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
        <remote-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>

        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>

        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
        <jms-queue name="JoeIsCool" entries="java:/jms/queue/JoeIsCool"/>

        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" ha="true" block-on-acknowledge="true" reconnect-attempts="-1" connectors="netty" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" transaction="xa" connectors="in-vm" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>


<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">

    ...
    <socket-binding name="messaging" port="5445"/>
    ...

</socket-binding-group>
```

I tried to create a simple test case that would send a message to the ActiveMQ Artemis instance:

```java
public void sendAmqMessage() throws Exception {
    final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin", "secretPassoword", "tcp://localhost:5445");
    final Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();
    final Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    final Destination destination = session.createQueue("JoeIsCool");
    final MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
    final TextMessage message =
    session.createTextMessage("Hello !!! Welcome to the world of ActiveMQ.");
    producer.send(message);
    connection.close();
}
```

Upon execution, I get this error on my client:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Cannot send, channel has already failed: tcp://127.0.0.1:5445
```

I get this error on my server:

```
(Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)) AMQ214013: Failed to decode packet: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AMQ219032: Invalid type: 1
```

I tried to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41157708/amq214013-failed-to-decode-packet-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-amq11903) in answering my own question but was unable to find a useful solution.

What am I missing in configuring the ActiveMQ instance, and how can I test it with Java code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `sendAmqMessage` method you're creating a `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` instance like so:

```java
final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin", "secretPassoword", "tcp://localhost:5445");
```

This `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` is from the ActiveMQ 5.x client and uses the OpenWire protocol which the `remote-acceptor` in your `standalone-full.xml` doesn't understand, hence the error about failing to decode the incoming backup.

As [the documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuring_messaging/acceptors_and_connectors) you're following suggests, instead of instantiating the `ConnectionFactory` directly you should simply look it up in JNDI like so:

```
final Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8080");
InitialContext remotingCtx = new InitialContext(env);
final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) remotingCtx.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
```

Also, make sure you're using the correct dependency, i.e.:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-jms-client-bom</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Using JNDI this way will also allow you to remove this from your `standalone-full.xml`:

```xml
<remote-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
<remote-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
```

As well as this:

```xml
<socket-binding name="messaging" port="5445"/>
```

You really only need the resources defined in the default `standalone-full.xml`.