# AMQ214013: Failed to decode packet

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am trying to run the samples provided for remote chunking in spring batch. While starting the master I get below exception. Anyone has a idea on this error code?

```
2022-08-03 06:15:10.381 ERROR 1303 --- [-netty-threads)] org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client  : AMQ214013: Failed to decode packet

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AMQ219032: Invalid type: 1
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.PacketDecoder.decode(PacketDecoder.java:499) ~[artemis-core-client-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ClientPacketDecoder.decode(ClientPacketDecoder.java:67) ~[artemis-core-client-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ClientPacketDecoder.decode(ClientPacketDecoder.java:42) ~[artemis-core-client-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:386) ~[artemis-core-client-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1265) ~[artemis-core-client-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:73) ~[artemis-core-client-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327) ~[netty-codec-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299) ~[netty-codec-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.kqueue.AbstractKQueueStreamChannel$KQueueStreamUnsafe.readReady(AbstractKQueueStreamChannel.java:544) ~[netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.kqueue.AbstractKQueueChannel$AbstractKQueueUnsafe.readReady(AbstractKQueueChannel.java:383) ~[netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoop.processReady(KQueueEventLoop.java:211) ~[netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoop.run(KQueueEventLoop.java:289) ~[netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) ~[artemis-commons-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]

2022-08-03 06:15:10.382 ERROR 1303 --- [-netty-threads)] org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client  : AMQ214031: Failed to decode buffer, disconnect immediately.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AMQ219032: Invalid type: 1
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:399) ~[artemis-core-client-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1265) ~[artemis-core-client-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:73) ~[artemis-core-client-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327) ~[netty-codec-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299) ~[netty-codec-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.kqueue.AbstractKQueueStreamChannel$KQueueStreamUnsafe.readReady(AbstractKQueueStreamChannel.java:544) ~[netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.kqueue.AbstractKQueueChannel$AbstractKQueueUnsafe.readReady(AbstractKQueueChannel.java:383) ~[netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoop.processReady(KQueueEventLoop.java:211) ~[netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoop.run(KQueueEventLoop.java:289) ~[netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) ~[artemis-commons-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AMQ219032: Invalid type: 1
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.PacketDecoder.decode(PacketDecoder.java:499) ~[artemis-core-client-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ClientPacketDecoder.decode(ClientPacketDecoder.java:67) ~[artemis-core-client-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ClientPacketDecoder.decode(ClientPacketDecoder.java:42) ~[artemis-core-client-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:386) ~[artemis-core-client-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    ... 21 common frames omitted

2022-08-03 06:15:10.393  WARN 1303 --- [global-threads)] org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client  : AMQ212037: Connection failure to localhost/127.0.0.1:61616 has been detected: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AMQ219032: Invalid type: 1 [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2022-08-03 06:15:39.723  INFO 1303 --- [           main] o.s.i.jms.JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint       : started bean 'inboundFlow.jms:message-driven-channel-adapter#0'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/example/demo/config/MasterConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'bean method inboundFlow'
2022-08-03 06:15:39.769  INFO 1303 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8085 (http) with context path ''
```

Comment: Can you provide any more details? What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using? What was the client's URL? How was ActiveMQ Artemis configured? Can you paste the `broker.xml`?

Comment: See if this one helps you somehow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41157708/amq214013-failed-to-decode-packet-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-amq11903

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when an application using the OpenWire JMS client library (which ships with ActiveMQ "Classic") tries to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis on a port where support for the OpenWire protocol is not configured.

Please ensure all your clients are using the core JMS client (which ships with ActiveMQ Artemis) or the acceptor which the OpenWire JMS clients are using supports the OpenWire protocol.

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
   <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
   <version>2.24.0</version>
  </dependency>
I have only above client in dependency.  I have not added OpenWire JMS client.

Comment: Is the broker on a network open to other clients?

Comment: Everything is in local. Downloaded and started the ActiveMQ locally. Trying to configure a spring boot process which will publish messages to ActiveMQ.

Comment: Well, it certainly looks like _something_ is connecting to ActiveMQ Artemis which shouldn't be. It wouldn't necessarily have to be an OpenWire JMS client, although that's the most common cause. You still haven't provided the details I requested previously (i.e. version, client URL, `broker.xml`).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error. I was running Camel 3 with Springboot 2 and have a local instance of activemq artemis running in localhost:61616. I was migrating old code from fuse 6 to springboot and apparently, i forgot to turn off my local fuse 6 server and it was also configured to send some data to localhost:61616. Just like what was mentioned in the comment, something is connecting to ActiveMQ which shouldn't be in the first place.